# Deploy nodejs + typescript project to heroku failed

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, deployment, nodemon

I've been triying to deploy my aplication build in nodejs and typescript to heroku. I've tried fixing my `package.json` to fix this issue but I just can't get it to work.

here's my `package.json`:

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "build",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/",
    "config/"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./typings"
  ],
  "types": "build/server.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build",
    "package.json",
    "package-lock.json",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build-ts",
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "node dist/src/server.js",
    "watch-node": "nodemon dist/src/server.js",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w"
  },
...
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.5",
    "underscore": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

and the error i keep getting in heroku:

```
 node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts(3309,5): error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
         Type '{ (): void; (chunk: Buffer): void; (callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: Callback<...>): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: () => void): this; (chunk: any, cb?: () => void): this; (chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, cb?: () => void): this; }'.
           Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
             'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.
       node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts(3309,5): error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'WritableStream'.
         Type '{ (): void; (chunk: Buffer): void; (callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, callback: Callback<void | GridFSFile>): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding): void; (chunk: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: Callback<...>): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: () => void): this; (data: string | Uint8Array, cb?: () => void): this; (str: string, encoding?: BufferEncoding, cb?: () => void): this; }'.
           Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
             'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.
       node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts(3310,5): error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
...
       npm ERR! code 2
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_605c623d
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c npm run build-ts
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.UJkYS/_logs/2022-01-14T04_20_17_340Z-debug.log
```

I dont have much experience deploying apps, please help

Comment: does it run locally?

Comment: yes. Everything runs good locally

Comment: are you building the project locally and pushing the compiled js? or are you building it on heroku?

Comment: Im building it on heroku with the github method

Comment: do you have typescript installed globally on your machine? seems like there is a version mismatch somewhere

Comment: try cloning down your repo into a clean folder (on a different machine if you can) and see if it builds correctly then